# In WPF app the filepath is not showing from right end in textbox

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have a textbox in WPF window to show the path of file and browse button beside the textbox, I am selecting a file from (tfs) browser and I want to show the full path aligned from right side but it is showing from left side only.
[The Image show the path showed from left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh2UO.png)

I tried HorizontalAlignment,VerticalAlignment,HorizontalContentAlignment but nothing is helping.

I want to display it from right end.

I have referred

[Show right end of text line in TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581405/show-right-end-of-text-line-in-textbox)

[TextBox.TextAlign right-side alignment has no effect in certain conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379731/textbox-textalign-right-side-alignment-has-no-effect-in-certain-conditions)

Can anyone Help?

### Here is the code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Source :&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.144,1.871" Margin="10,27,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSourceFile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="67,34,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" TextAlignment="Justify" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
        <Button x:Name="btnBrowseSource" Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="379,62,0,0" Click="btnBrowseSource_Click" />



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

OK, so its not that trivial as setting a property on text box what you can do is declare this method:

```
private void ScrollToEnd()
{
    var sv = (ScrollViewer)txtSourceFile.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", txtSourceFile);
        sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(sv.ExtentWidth);
}
```

And call it whenever your textbox value is changed.

Comment: Sir I did that, I had tried it before posting but it is not working and that is the reason I am surprised. Nothing seems to be working. I have read All the properties of textbox from MSDN. is it because the path is a TFS path not any normal windows directory path?

Comment: @GKhedekar try the new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and added a method for the *Loaded* and *TextChanged* event

```
<TextBox Loaded="FolderTB_ScrolltoEnd" TextChanged="FolderTB_ScrolltoEnd" ... />
```

and for setting the offset

```
private void FolderTB_ScrolltoEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).ScrollToHorizontalOffset(((TextBox)sender).ExtentWidth);
    }
```